# Explain features from my keras object with lime R package

Tags: python, r, deep-learning, keras, reticulate

After obtaining `accuracy` metric from my `keras` binary classification model, I need know what the model made the predictions. So, I'm interested in **variable importance**. I use `lime` package.

```
library(lime)

explainer <- lime (
  x  = x_train, 
  model  = model_keras, 
  bin_continuous  = FALSE)

explanation <- explain (
    x_test[1:20,], # Show first 20 samples
    explainer    = explainer, 
    n_labels     = 1, 
    n_features   = 5)
```

`Explain` function gives me the following error in `py_get_attr_impl` function: *AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'func_name'.*

I have compiled `keras` model with `R`, but this [Issue](https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/issues/29) seems to be that error comes from Python version. Problems with `Reticulate` package?

Comment: You need to define appropriate `lime::model_type()` and `lime::predict_model()` methods for your `keras` model. Can you share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Lime v0.4 is supposed to have native support for keras [https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/blog/lime-v0.4-the-kitten-picture-edition.html]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with python 2.7 but generates error with python 3+.

Actually function attribute `func_name` was renamed in python 3+ to `__name__`.

lime package (models.R) has a line:

```
if (keras::get_layer(x, index = -1)$activation$func_name == 'linear')
```

I removed `$func_name` and the code worked for me.
I suppose this is not the best workaround, however the possible solution that comes to mind:

```
if (keras::get_layer(x, index = -1)$activation$__name__ == 'linear')
```

did not work with R.

Comment: The full code was taken from here: http://www.business-science.io/business/2017/11/28/customer_churn_analysis_keras.html